# ffmpeg adding surround sound to video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video file which has 8 channel audio in it (not surround 7.1, but simply multiple channels).

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 result.mp4

video.mp4 is an h.264 video only file. audio.wav is a 8 channel wav file. If I import the audio.wav file into audacity, I see 8 channels of audio just like I would expect. If I combine the video and audio using above ffmpeg command, I get a file which has 8 channels of audio ust like I would hope, but channel 4 is changed to be low frequencies only as if it is made for subwoofer. I did confirm this by importing the audio from the result file into Audacity, and in fact the channel 3 is changed to LF only.

I am pretty sure that there is a way do disable this transformation or any other transformations so ffmpeg simply wraps the video and audio without any changes. Please let me know of any options that I need to call up to stop the LF filtering. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a work around and it seems to work.

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 result.mkv

Yes, if I specify for result to have "mkv" extension, the audio does not get changed and all 8 channels remain just as they were. So I did sort of answer my own question here, but I would like to know if there are any ffmpeg option that will disable LFE filtering for mp4.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Matroska container (MKV) has a different audio encoder as its default (vorbis). For the MPEG AAC codec, you'll need to set a channel layout which has no LFE channel, like octagonal. However, this is not a standard layout, so some AAC decoders will treat it as `7.1`

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -channel_layout octagonal result.mp4
```